# How to access immediate character of string in python

Tags: python

I'm working on small program which removes unit production in given grammar. I've developed one logic which is correct for me. The problem I'm facing is I cannot access next immediate index of a string stored in list in Python.

```
gram=[line.rstrip('\n') for line in open("grammar.txt","r+")]

non_terminals=[]
productions=[]
for item in range(len(gram)):
   non_terminals.append(gram[item][0])

   print(non_terminals)
   temp=[]
for item in range(len(gram)):
   for str in non_terminals:
     if gram[item][0] is str:
        productions.append(gram[item].lstrip(str).lstrip('-'+'>'))


 temp=''

for item in range(len(productions)):
   for str in range(len(productions[item])):
       for nt in non_terminals:
          if productions[item][str] is nt:
             if productions[item][str-1] is '|' and (productions[item]  [str+1] is '|'):
                 i=nt.index(nt)
                 temp=productions[item].rstrip(nt)
                 temp=temp+productions[i]

  print(productions)
  print(temp)
```

I'm getting error

> if productions[item][str-1] is '|' and (productions[item][str+1] is '|'):
>   IndexError: string index out of range

text file contains

```
S->S+T|T
T->T*F|F
F->(S)|a
```

Can anyone suggest that for what reason I'm not able to do so.?

Comment: Compare strings with `==` not `is`. Also, loop to `len(production) - 1`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I did replacements as you suggested, but that only helped me in removing error. Now it doesn't execute `if productions[item][str-1]=='|'` condition as it should execute when condition falls true.

Comment: I debugged my code I found out that code compares string from txt file leaving last character. That means it doesn't consider last character when I put `len(production)-1` in second loop. @AndrewL.